# MDX Query - Differece between two columns

Tags: mdx, olap-cube, saiku

It is possible to calculate a measure which is the difference between two members of the same dimension?
What I want to do is something like this:
([Year]. ["Year X"], [Measures]. [All]) - ([Year]. ["Year X - 1"], [Measures]. [All])
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the sample expected output?

Comment: I have to calculate the change (and the percent change) of a measure between two years, the current one and the previous one.

Comment: @mike5v was the answer I added correct?

Answer (score 0):

A measure using `lag` can be created:

```
([Year].CURRENTMEMBER, [Measures].[All]) - ([Year].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(1), [Measures].[All])
```

....but what is `[Measures].[All]` ?! Cubes don't have an `All` member in the `Measures` dimension.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do it this way.
I had written [Measures]. [Measure X], probably a moderator edited my question.